# Kivy: ScrollView squishes together the layout

Tags: kivy, scrollview

I am new to Kivy and this is my first time trying to create a scrollView.

I am trying to do a 'Splitwise' ripoff where you can create expenses and let the app figure out who should pay who etc.

I am trying to create a method that opens a popup with all members and their balances as well as a button with the text 'Settle up'. Underneath the balances should be a list of all the registered debts, and you should be able to scroll down to see them all. The popup should also contain a 'Cancel'-button.

My problem is that my code doesn't enable scrolling, and also squishes together the content in the pop up. [See picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGcTm.png)

All help highly appreciated!

See (messy) code below:

```
    sbl_ret = GridLayout(cols = 1)

    sbl_balances = GridLayout(cols = 3)

    sbl_balances.add_widget(Label())
    sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(text = 'Balances', font_size = '20sp', size_hint = (1,.2), color = backgroundColor, bold = True))
    sbl_balances.add_widget(Label())

    for member in self.members:

        sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(text = member.getName(), font_size = 40, size_hint_y = None, height = 60))

        sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(text = str(round(member.getBalance())) + ' kr', font_size = 40, size_hint_y = None, height = 60))

        sbl2 = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        sbl2.add_widget(Label(size_hint = (1,.2)))
        btn = Button(text = 'Settle up', background_color = buttonColor, bold = True, size_hint_y = None, height = 60)
        btn.bind(on_press = lambda member: self.settleUp())
        sbl2.add_widget(btn)
        sbl2.add_widget(Label(size_hint = (1,.2)))
        sbl_balances.add_widget(sbl2)


    sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(size_hint = (.2,1)))
    sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(text = 'Debts', font_size = '20sp', color = backgroundColor, bold = True))
    sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(size_hint = (.2,1)))
    for member in self.members:
        for debt in member.getDebtList():
            sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(size_hint = (.2,1)))
            sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(size_hint_y = None, height = 60, text = debt.getToWhom().getName() + ' lent ' + str(debt.getAmount()) + ' SEK to ' + debt.getFromWhom().getName() + ' for ' + debt.getDescription(), font_size = 40))
            sbl_balances.add_widget(Label(size_hint = (.2,1)))

    sbl_balances.bind(minimum_height=sbl_balances.setter('height'))

    sbl3 = BoxLayout(size_hint = (1,.15))
    sbl3.add_widget(Label(size_hint = (.2,1)))
    b = Button(text = 'Cancel', background_color = entryColor, size_hint_y = None, height = 150)
    b.bind(on_press = lambda x: self.balanceDialog.dismiss())
    sbl3.add_widget(b)
    sbl3.add_widget(Label(size_hint = (.2,1)))

    sv = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False)
    sv.add_widget(sbl_balances)

    sbl_ret.add_widget(sv)
    sbl_ret.add_widget(sbl3)


    self.balanceDialog = Popup(title = 'Group view', content = sbl_ret, title_align = 'center',
        title_color = backgroundColor, background_color = [0,0,0,.7], separator_height = 0, title_size = '28sp')
    self.balanceDialog.open()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `size_hint_y=None` to your code creating the `GridLayout`:

```
sbl_balances = GridLayout(cols = 3, size_hint_y=None)
```

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#managing-the-content-size-and-position).